# How to remove leading zeros in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad

basically I have a txt file containing data below. How to use regex function to remove the leading 0s?

`Input:
20100327        15,18,37,39,44,52
20100328        02,08,24,31,33,50
20100330        16,26,27,39,40,46
20100522        05,07,10,11,13,27`

Result:
20100327        15,18,37,39,44,52
20100328        2,8,24,31,33,50
20100330        16,26,27,39,40,46
20100522        5,7,10,11,13,27

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    \b0+
Replace: (empty)
```

### Demo

This logic works, at least with the data you did show us, because all leading zeroes which you would want to remove always have a word boundary on the left side.  Zeroes which should be retained would always have a digit on the left side.